# WordPress is randomly returning XML (RSS feed?) instead of web page

Tags: xml, wordpress, amazon-ec2, http-headers, replication

One of our Wordpress sites returns pages as XML instead of HTML on a random basis, perhaps 1 out of every 30-100 or so page refreshes.  It seems that we are not alone: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-displaying-rss-feed-instead-of-website?replies=16#post-2951783

We are hosting in Amazon EC2 and running the site on replicated web servers.

Can anyone shed some light on the problem and a solution?

Answer (score 3):

We had this problem at work recently, though this particular site in question is just being served on vanilla Apache: not sure if this advice also applies to EC2 or not. (We use EC2 as well, I simply have no personal experience with it.)

To test, we went to the RSS feed directly and checked the links. Turns out Apache was caching the RSS feed, overwriting all web requests for `/*`, sending them to the RSS feed.

Turning off `mod_cache` appears to have completely resolved the problem.

May not help with EC2--may be outside the purview of most people's problems like this--but I'll add my answer here "just in case." ;)